# Troubleshooting kubectl get pods command: Why is .spec.containers.ports.containerPort returning <none>?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I am getting the IP address assigned to the pod using `kubectl get pods -o custom-columns="POD_IP":.status.podIPs` command.

And based on same approach, I am using `kubectl get pods -o custom-columns="POD_PORT":.spec.containers.ports.containerPort` command to get the port number but it is coming as blank.

```
cloudshell:~$ kubectl get pods -o custom-columns="POD_IP":.status.podIPs
POD_IP
[map[ip:10.32.0.194]]

cloudshell:~$ kubectl get pods -o custom-columns="POD_PORT":.spec.containers.ports.containerPort
POD_PORT
<none>

cloudshell:~$ kubectl get pods -o custom-columns="POD_PORT":.spec.containers
POD_PORT
[map[image:nginx:1.10.1 imagePullPolicy:IfNotPresent name:servic1 ports:[map[containerPort:8080 protocol:TCP]] resources:map[limits:map[cpu:500m ephemeral-storage:1Gi memory:2Gi] requests:map[cpu:500m ephemeral-storage:1Gi memory:2Gi]] securityContext:map[capabilities:map[drop:[NET_RAW]]] terminationMessagePath:/dev/termination-log terminationMessagePolicy:File volumeMounts:[map[mountPath:/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount name:kube-api-access-mgk8k readOnly:true]]]]

cloudshell:~$
```

I have tried to use `kubectl get pods -o custom-columns="Port Number of Pod":.spec.containers` command and I can see that my mapping (`.spec.containers.ports.containerPort`) is correct but somehow it is still not working.

I am totally sure that `.spec.containers.ports.containerPort` mapping correct, and same command format is giving IP address, so not able to catch what is wrong.

Is anyone able to catch what is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```bash
kubectl get pods \
--output=custom-columns=\
"POD_PORT":.spec.containers[*].ports[*].containerPort
```

You can include `.metadata.name` too to aid clarity:

```bash
kubectl get pods \
--output=custom-columns=\
"NAME":.metadata.name,\
"POD_PORT":.spec.containers[*].ports[*].containerPort
```

It's not clearly (!?) [documented](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/#custom-columns) but I suspect the format is kubectl's [JSONPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) and there (appears to be) a subtle distinction between e.g. `.spec.containers[]` and `.spec.containers[*]` where the former stops when the property is not found and the latter includes everything.

Because `.spec` will always include one or more `.containers`, but each `container` may not have `.ports`, you can also:

```bash
kubectl get pods \
--output=custom-columns=\
"POD_PORT":.spec.containers[].ports[*].containerPort
```

Which `containers[]` but `ports[*]` to the same effect.

**NOTE** as explained in [Container v1 core](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.26/#container-v1-core) see "ports", ports that are exposed by the container need not be specified through `ports` i.e. this command will return documented ports but this list may exclude ports that are exposed by the containers (and not documented).

Comment: I really thought over it but couldn't see the issue. Great answer. Thanks.